# If statement that checks select query is being ignored

Tags: php, mediawiki, mediawiki-extensions

I got the following code:

```
if(isset($_POST['vote'])){

        if (!$wgUser->isLoggedIn()) {
            // User is not online, don't accept the vote, set error message
            $msg = 'Login required to vote.';
        } if ($wgUser->isBlocked()) {
            // User is banned, don't accept the vote, set error message
            $msg = 'Account is banned.';
        } else {
            // User is online and not banned
            $buildId = htmlspecialchars($_POST['id'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
            $rating = htmlspecialchars($_POST['rating'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
            $comment = htmlspecialchars($_POST['comment'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
            $res = $db->select(
                'build_rating',
                array('article_id', 'username', 'vote', 'comment', 'date'),
                array('article_id' => $buildId, 'username' => $wgUser->getName()),
                __METHOD__
            );

            // Did user already vote on this build?
            if (!$res) {
                // Yes, let's update the vote and set success message
                $db->update(
                    'build_rating',
                    array('vote' => $rating, 'comment' => $comment),
                    array('article_id' => $buildId, 'username' => $wgUser->getName()),
                    __METHOD__
                );
                $msg = 'Your vote has been successfully updated.';

            } else {
                // No, let's insert the vote and set success message
                $db->insert(
                    'build_rating',
                    array('article_id' => $buildId, 'username' => $wgUser->getName(), 'vote' => $rating, 'comment' => $comment),
                    __METHOD__
                );
                $msg = 'Your vote has been successfully saved.';
            }
        }
    }
```

that is suposed to save a users rating on a specific article. Everything seems to be working correctly besides the if statements that check whether the user has already voted (in that case it should just update the rating) or if it's a brand new vote (in that case it should save it as a new vote). For some reason the if statements don't work since each vote is being saved as a new vote. A user can simply place 100 votes when he should in fact only be able to place just one per article. Could someone point out my error?

Comment: You shouldn't use `htmlspecialchars` when storing into the DB. It should be used only when displaying on a web page.

Comment: Could that be the issue? Also, do you mean like this: `$output->addHTML( htmlspecialchars($outP], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8') );`?

Comment: I don't think it has anything to do with the issue, it was just general advice.

Comment: Alright, I managed to solve the issue. Regarding your tip, how would I do it?

Comment: I don't know the MediaWiki API, but that looks about right.

Comment: Typically you would use [`Html::element()`](https://doc.wikimedia.org/mediawiki-core/master/php/classHtml.html#a820804c8471efa2b792a160c05d2d59b).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what database library that is, but maybe that call to select() returns an iterator.

```
if (count($res) == 0) {
    // update    
}
```

Comment: https://doc.wikimedia.org/mediawiki-core/master/php/classDatabaseBase.html#a76f9e6cb7b145a3d9020baebf94b499e It seems like it returns bool?

Comment: @Muki It says: _If the query returned no rows, a ResultWrapper with no rows in it will be returned._ It only returns `false` if there was an error and the _ignore errors_ option is set.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve the issue, you are required to enter the following `if ($res->numRows())`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of counting rows in $res as suggested, you can also use selectRow() instead of select(). selectRow will return the (first) matching row, or false if there is none.

Answer (score 0):

Just use [`upsert()`](https://doc.wikimedia.org/mediawiki-core/master/php/classDatabaseBase.html#aaf64d9422b01b19ca0620a8cfe5641e0); that will do the select/insert/update combo in a single query. The PHP code is going to look simpler and the operation will be [atomic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomicity_(database_systems)), which will spare you all the nasty race condition errors.